# Add the same value to each element in a column with PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to add 10 points to each of my students grades with PLSQL.

```
UPDATE AverageView SET AverageModifier = 10 WHERE COURSE_ID = 'INFO101' AND GROUP_ID = 101 AND SEMESTER = 'SUMER14';
```

So when I try to update the view, I want this trigger activated and I want to use INSTEAD OF UPDATE and modify the real tables. Like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ChangeAverage 
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON AverageView
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 

UPDATE INSCRIPTIONS SET grade = (grade + 10) WHERE COURSE_ID = :NEW.COURSE_ID AND GROUP_ID = :NEW.GROUP_ID AND SEMESTER = :NEW.SEMESTER ;


END;
/
```

I added a +10 ''manually'' but eventually it will be a just a variable.

```
 UPDATE INSCRIPTIONS SET grade = (grade + modifier) ....
```

I think it doesn't work because there is more than one grades to update, and I am stuck there.

When I remove the grade and set a static value it ''kind of'' work, but it's setting all the student grades to 10.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ChangeAverage 
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON AverageView
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 

UPDATE INSCRIPTIONS SET grade = 10 WHERE COURSE_ID = :NEW.COURSE_ID AND GROUP_ID = :NEW.GROUP_ID AND SEMESTER = :NEW.SEMESTER ;
END;
/
```

Should I use a loop and a cursor ?

My inscriptions table looks like this :

```
STUDENT_ID        CHAR(12)  NOT NULL,
COURSE_ID         CHAR(12)  NOT NULL,
GROUP_ID          INTEGER   NOT NULL,
SEMESTER          CHAR(12)  NOT NULL,
REGISTRATION_DATE DATE  NOT NULL,
GRADE         INTEGER,
```

My AverageView is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW AverageView AS
SELECT COURSE_ID, GROUP_ID, SEMESTER, AVG(GRADE) AS Average
FROM Inscriptions
GROUP BY COURSE_ID, GROUP_ID, SEMESTER
/
```

From what I know of the views, they cant be modified. Instead I modify the inscription table.

Lets say my inscriptions table look like this

```
Student A, INFO101, 101, SUMER14, ramdom_date, 70
Student B, INFO101, 101, SUMER14, ramdom_date, 50
```

My view works perfectly : It outputs an average of 60 for this course.

Now, with my trigger, I want to boost the average.

```
 UPDATE AverageView SET AverageModifier = 10 WHERE COURSE_ID = 'INFO101' AND GROUP_ID = 101 AND SEMESTER = 'SUMER14';
```

But from what I know, I cannot modify the content of an view, so I want to add 10 (for now) to every grade in the table inscriptions.

So the trigger will result something like that :

```
Student A, INFO101, 101, SUMER14, ramdom_date, 80
Student B, INFO101, 101, SUMER14, ramdom_date, 60
```

Best regards

Comment: Structure of your table `INSCRIPTIONS`, view `AverageView` and some example data would be usefull to help you.

Comment: I updated the question, I added some more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ChangeAverage 
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON AverageView
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 

UPDATE INSCRIPTIONS SET grade = (:old.grade + 10) WHERE COURSE_ID = :NEW.COURSE_ID AND GROUP_ID = :NEW.GROUP_ID AND SEMESTER = :NEW.SEMESTER ;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had a constraint which was not updated and was keeping me from updating within certain parameters. I guess we can delete the question !